# Suggestions on correlation analysis of different time series

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation

I have a uni project that requires correlation analysis of different time series but I don't have background in the field of statistical analysis. It's a comparison of google trends data with data such as housing prices or population I would really appreciate it if there is any suggestions on the recommended approaches for the analysis of my project. Thank you!

Comment: You have data and are choosing an analysis? Or you are choosing data as well? Also, what field is the project in? (e.g. geography, economics,  statistics, machine learning?)

Comment: It's a study about exploring the possibilities of using Google Trends data to understand community behaviour. Essentially it involves investigating search engine queries about water-related topics and relating it to historical economic, biophysical, climatic and population factors (water prices, damn inflows, rainfall). One of the aim is to reveal more information about people's concern. The field is probably in environmental sustainability. Cheers!

Comment: Then I would suggest you try to come up with a hypothesis (or several) about relationships you might expect to see. (Possibly after some preliminary exploratory data analysis/visualization.) Then you could try to test these hypotheses statistically. If you have a particular data set and hypothesis, you will be able to get much more useful responses here.

Comment: Let's say for instance my hypothesis is an increase water price will cause an increase in search volume for the term "water price" and i have the two sets of data in the same time step or possibly if there's a time lag. What kind of analysis can I approach to prove the hypothesis? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You might post this example in your question, to make it more concrete. If you have time series for price and search volume, then exploratory data analysis would start with visualizing the co-plotted series, as well as their respective distributions (e.g. histograms). Cross-correlation could be a reasonable next step, but of course correlation is not causation.

Comment: You could include the information from the comments into the original post, that would improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll post the question when I have the examples and information better prepared!